# Best PC rig for Google Sheets / 20+ tabs in 2022?

Tags: pc, desktop, performance

I have a budget of about $1500 - $2000 for a new PC. Want to go desktop this time (I've been on laptops only for years). Run a home-based business that requires 10-15 Chrome tabs open at once (sometimes 20). Mostly Google Sheets. A few Gmail windows. on the Google sheets, I have one that's constantly around the 5,000,000 cells limit. It gets laggy sometimes.

So just curious what to go for to get optimal performance, given those specs. I don't want to build my own.

Appreciate your help,

Dan

Comment: Do you have brand preferences? Where do you live?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the 24” M1 iMac, and there are a number of reasons for this system being the choice.

1. Price: $1,529 for 16 GB and Gigabit Ethernet.
2. The 4.5K 24” with 4480 by 2520 pixels compares well to larger monitors like the 32" Samsung A700.
3. The M1 is generally faster than Intel i9 (Coffee Lake/9th) for benchmarks and real world use.
4. Unified memory shares the 16 GB of RAM between CPU and GPU with no copying.
5. The SSD is at least as fast as most high end Gen3 NVMe.
6. Four Thunderbolt 4/USB 4 ports.
7. Web Cam with good quality.
8. Compact design.
9. Google has native support for all their Apps on Apple Silicon.

Comparing this system to most any other similar system, you find most other systems have trade-offs. Or they cost significantly more.